# Visual Studio Team Services Build Notifications

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there any way to get the visual studio build notification tool to work with the new vNext build system?

Currently all I can see are the old xaml workflow based builds available to select for notifications.

I would like to also be able to use this for the vNext scriptable build system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For VS notification, only XAML build definitions will have notifications. Right now, configure email alert is the only option.

By the way, here is an extensible plugin for TFS named TfsNotificationRelay supports sending notifications to Slack, HipChat and IRC, including notifications for vNext build events, you may take a look at it: https://github.com/kria/TfsNotificationRelay

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see the current build status in tray, you can use [Catlight](https://catlight.io). It supports new vNext builds and Visual Studio Online.

Answer (score 2):

Another option to get vNext notification is use of [AnyStatus](http://www.anystat.us/)

Now available as VS extension and will come with desktop app.

Comment: For the record, AnyStatus provides a way to monitor your entire development environment in addition to build and release notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a CatLight no longer being free, I've developed a replacement - system tray notifications and a website dashboard for TFS builds (VSTS or on-premises). Early stages but the first version is available here: https://github.com/mattwendels/tfs-build-notifications